# AWS ElasticBeanstalk EC2 gives postgresql connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

When I deploy my app on aws beanstalk using `eb deploy` it gives an error

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

.ebextensions/postgres.config:

```
packages:
yum:
 postgresql93-devel: []
```

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
# For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
pool: 5

production:
<<: *default
database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: Do you have an RDS instance in your Data Tier configuration under the environment your are deploying to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue.

The problem is that you have to connect your database to the application through the environment variables.

First you need to create an RDS instance to connect to. This link shows you how: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-connect-postgresql-db/?nc1=h_ls

Then, after the instance is created, you need to go to the RDS Service page, and choose instance in the left menu. Choose the instance you created in the list and proceed to the section called "Connect". Those are the values you put inside those environment variables, with the HOSTNAME value being the endpoint.

Hope it helped, worked for me!

Comment: Heya, I'm running into this same issue. Wondering if you could provide a speicifc example of your solution? Like, how exactly do you replace the environment variable values with those values?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but in my case the RDS connection was timing out. The solution was add the security group of my EC2 instance to the "inbound" section of the RDS security group.

To do this go to EC2 page and search for "Security Groups", there you can find your RDS and EC2 security groups, click in the RDS security group and add the EC2 security group.

Answer (score 0):

I got the `PG::ConnectionBad` error too, with it timing out. Thanks to @Mateus for pointing out what to do, but I'll expand on his answer for helpfulness.

### Diagnose & test

To prove the problem (and you've fixed it), simple `eb ssh` to your server, and run:

```
psql -h xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com -d ebdb -U postgres
```

to connect directly to the RDS instance. It will either fail immediately, or take a long time and then timeout. When you're done, it will ask for your password and then work!

## Solve the problem

I had to add the security group of my EC2 instance to the Inbound section of the RDS security group.

To do this for ElasticBeanstalk:

- Go to RDS in the AWS console, and select your database instance
- Scroll down to "Security group rules" and click on the security group for Inbound. (EC2 Security Group - Inbound)
- This will take you to the security groups list, filtered to the RDS one. I recommend to duplicate this tab, remove the filter, and find the group of your **new** EB environment. There are 2 of them. Find the one that's the equivalent of the Security Group ID that *already* had an inbound rule. And COPY that Security Group ID.
- Back on the first tab with the selected SecurityGroup, Click on Inbound Rules tab -> Edit inbound rules

  - Type: PostgreSQL  (Protocol TCP; Port range 5432)
  - Source: Custom
  - Paste in the new EB's security group id
  - Description: <your_own_description_to_help_you_remember_what_it_is>
- Save.

[image: InboundRules]

Then re-run the test above, and it should work!